# Convert IMFSample* to ID3D11ShaderResourceView*

Tags: c++, video, directx-11, ms-media-foundation

I am new to DirectX an I am trying to do a simple application that reads a video and display it on a Quad.

I read the video using Windows Media Foundation (IMFSourceReader), that sends me a callback when a sample is decoded (IMFSample).

I want to convert this IMFSample* to a ID3D11ShaderResourceView* in order to use it as a texture to draw my quad, however the conversion fails.

Here is what I do (I removed non relevant error checks):

```
HRESULT SourceReaderCB::OnReadSample(HRESULT hrStatus, DWORD dwStreamIndex, DWORD dwStreamFlags, LONGLONG llTimestamp, IMFSample *pSample)
{
    ...
    DWORD NumBuffers = 0;
    hr = pSample->GetBufferCount(&NumBuffers);

    if (FAILED(hr) || NumBuffers < 1)
    {
        ...
    }

    IMFMediaBuffer* SourceMediaPtr = nullptr;
    hr = pSample->GetBufferByIndex(0, &SourceMediaPtr);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        ...
    }

    ComPtr<IMFMediaBuffer> _pInputBuffer = SourceMediaPtr;
    ComPtr<IMF2DBuffer2> _pInputBuffer2D2;

    bool isVideoFrame = (_pInputBuffer.As(&_pInputBuffer2D2) == S_OK);
    if (isVideoFrame)
    {
        IMFDXGIBuffer* pDXGIBuffer = NULL;
        ID3D11Texture2D* pSurface = NULL;

        hr = _pInputBuffer->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IMFDXGIBuffer), (LPVOID*)&pDXGIBuffer);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            SafeRelease(&SourceMediaPtr);
            goto done;
        }

        hr = pDXGIBuffer->GetResource(__uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&pSurface);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            ...
        }

        ID3D11ShaderResourceView* resourceView;

        if (pSurface)
        {
            D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC textureDesc;
            pSurface->GetDesc(&textureDesc);

            D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC shaderResourceViewDesc;
            shaderResourceViewDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8_UNORM;
            shaderResourceViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
            shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
            shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;

            ID3D11ShaderResourceView* resourceView;
            hr = d3d11device->CreateShaderResourceView(pSurface, &shaderResourceViewDesc, &resourceView);
            if (FAILED(hr))
            {
                ... // CODE FAILS HERE
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

My first issue is that I set the shaderResourceViewDesc.Format as DXGI_FORMAT_R8_UNORM which will probably just give me red image (I will have to investigate this later).

The second and blocking issue I am facing ius that the conversion of ID3D11Texture2D to ID3D11ShaderResourceView fails with following error message:

```
ID3D11Device::CreateShaderResourceView: A ShaderResourceView cannot be created of a Resource that did not specify the D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE BindFlag. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #129: CREATESHADERRESOURCEVIEW_INVALIDRESOURCE]
```

I understand that there is a flag missing at the creation of the texture that prevents me to do what I want to do, but as the data buffer is created by WMF, I am not sure what I am supposed to do to fix this issue.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug output suggests that the texture is not compatible, as it was created without `D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE` flag (specified in `BindFlag` field of [`D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC` structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476253).

You read the texture already created by Media Foundation primitive. In some cases you can alter the creation flags, however the general case is that you need to create a compatible texture on your own, copy the data between the textures, and then call `CreateShaderResourceView` method with your texture as an argument rather than original texture.

Answer (score 4):

I see you code, and I can say that your way is wrong - no offense. Firstly, video decoder creates simple texture - in you situation DirectX11 texture - it is a regular texture - it is not shader resource, as a result it cannot be used in shader code. In my view, there are two way for resolving of your task:

1. Research - [Walkthrough: Using MF to render video in a Direct3D app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207074(v=vs.105).aspx) - this link present way for "Walkthrough: Using Microsoft Media Foundation for Windows Phone 8" - from your code I see that you try write solution for WindowsStore - UWP and code for Windows Phone is workable - this code needs `MediaEnginePlayer` - The MediaEnginePlayer class serves as a helper class that wraps the MF APIs;
2. Find on GitHub Windows-classic-samples and find in that `DX11VideoRenderer` - this is full code of Media Foundation renderer with DirectX11 - it includes very good example for using of DirectX11 Video Processor which does blitting of regular video texture from decoder into the rendering video texture of swap-chain:
   2.1. Get rendering texture from Swap Chain:

   ```
       // Get Backbuffer
   hr = m_pSwapChain1->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)&pDXGIBackBuffer);
   if (FAILED(hr))
   {
       break;
   }
   ```

   2.2. Create from rendering texture output view of video processor:

   ```
   //
   // Create Output View of Output Surfaces.
   //
   D3D11_VIDEO_PROCESSOR_OUTPUT_VIEW_DESC OutputViewDesc;
   ZeroMemory( &OutputViewDesc, sizeof( OutputViewDesc ) );
   if (m_b3DVideo && m_bStereoEnabled)
   {
       OutputViewDesc.ViewDimension =  D3D11_VPOV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2DARRAY;
   }
   else
   {
       OutputViewDesc.ViewDimension =  D3D11_VPOV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
   }
   OutputViewDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;
   OutputViewDesc.Texture2DArray.MipSlice = 0;
   OutputViewDesc.Texture2DArray.FirstArraySlice = 0;
   if (m_b3DVideo && 0 != m_vp3DOutput)
   {
       OutputViewDesc.Texture2DArray.ArraySize = 2; // STEREO
   }

   QueryPerformanceCounter(&lpcStart);

   hr  = m_pDX11VideoDevice->CreateVideoProcessorOutputView(pDXGIBackBuffer, m_pVideoProcessorEnum, &OutputViewDesc, &pOutputView);
   ```

2.3. Create from regular decoder video texture input view for video processor:

```
    D3D11_VIDEO_PROCESSOR_INPUT_VIEW_DESC InputLeftViewDesc;
    ZeroMemory( &InputLeftViewDesc, sizeof( InputLeftViewDesc ) );
    InputLeftViewDesc.FourCC = 0;
    InputLeftViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_VPIV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    InputLeftViewDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;
    InputLeftViewDesc.Texture2D.ArraySlice = dwLeftViewIndex;

    hr = m_pDX11VideoDevice->CreateVideoProcessorInputView(pLeftTexture2D, m_pVideoProcessorEnum, &InputLeftViewDesc, &pLeftInputView);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        break;
    }
```

2.4. Do blitting of regular decoder video texture on rendering texture from Swap Chain:

```
    D3D11_VIDEO_PROCESSOR_STREAM StreamData;
    ZeroMemory( &StreamData, sizeof( StreamData ) );
    StreamData.Enable = TRUE;
    StreamData.OutputIndex = 0;
    StreamData.InputFrameOrField = 0;
    StreamData.PastFrames = 0;
    StreamData.FutureFrames = 0;
    StreamData.ppPastSurfaces = NULL;
    StreamData.ppFutureSurfaces = NULL;
    StreamData.pInputSurface = pLeftInputView;
    StreamData.ppPastSurfacesRight = NULL;
    StreamData.ppFutureSurfacesRight = NULL;

    if (m_b3DVideo && MFVideo3DSampleFormat_MultiView == m_vp3DOutput && pRightTexture2D)
    {
        StreamData.pInputSurfaceRight = pRightInputView;
    }

    hr = pVideoContext->VideoProcessorBlt(m_pVideoProcessor, pOutputView, 0, 1, &StreamData );
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        break;
    }
```

Yes, they are sections of complex code, and it needs research whole `DX11VideoRenderer` project for understanding of it - it will take huge amount of time.

Regards,

Evgeny Pereguda

Comment: Thank you very much for your long and detailed answer, and no offense taken! I am actually very new at DirectX API